# Creating a 2-D plot using three parameters in IDL

Tags: plot, idl

I am able to create a 2-D plot using two parameters in IDL, i.e., star formation rate (y-axis) vs. time (x-axis).

But I would like to include the redshift (another variable) corresponding to each data point, say, as the top x-axis. It didn't work when I tried adding the third variable to PLOT procedure, and I have not been able to find any discussion on how to accomplish this online. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First run `PLOT.PRO` with the `NODATA` keyword set and `XAXIS=4` and `YAXIS=4` to suppress each axis.  Then you can use the `AXIS.PRO` program to define each axis.  Then you can use `OPLOT.PRO` to draw the points of Z vs. X and Z vs. Y, where Z = star formation rate, X = time, and Y = redshift.  Look up details on the `[XYZ]AXIS` keywords to determine which axis to draw at each time.  You can even color each axis using the `COLOR` keyword with the `AXIS.PRO` program.

The only trick is that you will have to scale the Y data points to the X-axis scale prior to plotting because you will explicitly define the `[XYZ]RANGE` when calling `PLOT.PRO` (well you could do the converse and scale it to Y and redefine X, it's your choice).  You need to do this scaling because `OPLOT.PRO` and, say, `PLOTS.PRO` use the original `[XYZ]RANGE` defined when calling `PLOT.PRO` to convert device coordinates to data coordinates.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the color to be the third dimension (ie. color or size).

Answer (score 0):

first call PLOT, TIME, SFR with XSTYLE=9 to force exact range and suppress the top x-axis

then use the AXIS procedure to create the top x-axis
be careful with the ticks of that axis, which you want to correspond to a REDSHIFT that you compute from the TIME variable

example with a bottom x-axis in velocity and a top y-axis in frequency:

```
> plot, vel, spec, xsty=9, xtick_get=xtick, xtit='Velocity (km/s)', ytit='Antenna Temperature (K)'
> axis, !x.crange[0], !y.crange[1], xaxis=1, xtickv=((ref_freq - ref_freq/299792.458*xtick)), xtickformat='(F8.3)', xticks=n_elements(xtick)-1, xrange=(ref_freq - ref_freq/299792.458*minmax(!x.crange)), chars=1.5
```